# How to change the Output value in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: xml, date, odoo, openerp-7

I am using Openerp 7 and I want to change the Output value on a Condition in the `view.xml`.

It should be something like that:

```
<field name="date" string="Date" attrs="{ 'value' : ('date' , '==' , False) ? 'No Date' : date}"/>
```

Is there a specific Attribute to set the Value or is there a other common way?

and also I don't want to create a computed Field.

Comment: `attrs` looks like `attrs="{'invisible': [('state','=','draft')]}"`

Comment: I dont wanna make it invisible, i want to change the value.

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: If the date is False, it should be not Empthy, it should print 'No Date'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `paceholder` attribute in xml view:

```
<field name="date_invoice" placeholder="No Date"/>
```